# How to Get Datasource from sublayout using glassmapper

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

I know in MVC you could do `this.GetLayoutItem<Model>()` to get the datasource of rendering on a page. How do we make use of this in sublayouts (.ascx)?

Comment: Be a little more specific in your question. Is this for iOS, java, ... ? Also add any code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit your user control from the `GlassUserControl` the `AbstractGlassUserControl` has properties for `LayoutItem` which will give you the datasource if its defined or there is a `DataSourceItem` property which returns the datasource explicitly.

[Using GlassUserControl](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial5)